# Add File on Alfresco Server in java

Tags: java

how to add file as per given target node on Alresco Server in java ?? I am getting Repository Exception and tyr to remove then getting Path not found Exception can any one guide me the solution

```
String path = node.getPath(); 
int index = path.lastIndexOf("/"); 
String newPathName = path.substring(0, index); 
newPathName = newPathName + "/" + node.getName(); 
session.move(path, newPathName);
```

Comment: Can you please share your code?

Comment: String path = node.getPath();                                     int index = path.lastIndexOf("/");                            String newPathName = path.substring(0, index);           newPathName = newPathName + "/" + node.getName(); session.move(path, newPathName);

Comment: session.move(node.getPath(), "/app:company_home/app:user_homes/cm:admin/cm:tests");

We have absolute path and target path in this method. I am using jcr 1.0 version jar.

I am getting Repository exception. If i given hard coded path that time also given repository Exception. Please provide solution ASAP. Thanks

Comment: does your newPathName start with a number?

Comment: newPathName="/app:company_home/app:user_homes/cm:admin/cm:test_space/cm:0000000162";  New path name is test_space i am try to moving in test_space directory.